# Mapping a User Folder Using a Login Script

Tags: script, login

This is a very trivial question, but I'm new to scripting. I'm trying to map a user's folder (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures, etc.) to any network workstation they login to using a login script. Basically, when there are not working on their assigned workstations, I would like them to have access to their data. I tried using `net use Y: "\\%ComputerName%\%USERPROFILE%"`, but that did not work. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'll state an example. User_1's assigned computer is Desktop_1. All of User1's files are located in C:\Users\User_1\ on Desktop_1. When User_1 is not using Desktop_1, I would like his/her files available on another desktop by mapping the %USERPROFILE% folder on Desktop_1. I would like to configure a general script that I can use for all users in their AD profile tab. So far, I have come up with net use Y: "\\%ComputerName%\C$\Users\%username%", but that doesn't work when the user logs into Desktop_2, because the Computer Name changes. Hope this clarifies the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment you don't need to script this, Windows supports a group policy for Roaming Profiles which stores all user data in a remote folder location.

The concept for roaming profiles is:

- The User profile %USERPROFILE% is redirected from C:\Users<username> to a remote central server e.g. `\\FileServer\Users\<username>`.
- Every time a user logs in this is automatically mapped.

There is [a full extensive guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/deploy-roaming-user-profiles) that covers all aspects and I suggest you read through this, but essentially you configure the GPO `User Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Folder Redirection`

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm trying to avoid roaming profiles or folder redirection, as the desktops are slow and quiet old. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a highly unusual thing to want to do. However, assuming all users and workstations are part of the same AD domain and, deducing from your current attempts all your users are either domain admins, or local admins on the workstations you can just configured a home drive.

As you’ve already discovered you need to have a reference point for what computer a user is normally a part of and where their data is stored.

My suggestion is that you set the user’s home drive, in the user’s Active Directory profile, to the exact path where their files are and set an appropriate drive letter for it.

For instance `user1` who works on `computer3` should have their Active Directory profile set so that their home folder is `\\computer3\c$\users\user1`. It’s arbitrary, but you could set the `H:` drive to be connected to this home folder.

In this way, whenever and wherever the user logs on there will be an H: drive connected to their user profile. Even on the system they usually work on.

Now, if these users do not have administrative permissions on these computers then they can not access the `C$` administrative share. In that case you will need to share the user profile folder and set the appropriate share permissions. In most cases the user should be the owner and the only one with access to their user profile folder, which is set via NTFS permissions. So, if this is true, you can simply grant `everyone` full control on the share (NOT NTFS) permissions. In this way, the NTFS permissions will control access both locally and remotely and you don’t have to worry about the specific share permissions. You would then connect the home drive to `\\computer3\user1` for instance - if you shared their profile folder as `user1`.

These settings can all be scripted as well, but I get the sense we’re not dealing with a large organization here so manually doing this will be sufficient.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the home drive option. This sounds like a solution that might work. The users only have domain user rights for security reasons, but I'm pretty sure I can find a workaround. You are of course correct, there are only twenty users. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do agree with others, this is solving the X-Y problem the wrong way, I do spot your error.

%USERPROFILE% is set to C:\Users\Username. This contains chars impossible for a share.

In Addition %Computername% is translated at logon to the computer they are currently on, not the computer that is their main computer, so that means that you will have to create a logon script that checks for every username and makes the mapping there. This of course means that every single change (new user, change of computer etc) will mean editing the script.

Here is a sample of your batch login script:

```
::  -- Login script: Maps Extra share if user is not on main computer
    if %USERNAME%==John goto John
    if %USERNAME%==Mark goto Mark

::  -- USERS LOGIN -------

:John
    if %COMPUTERNAME%==PC0007 goto end
    net use y: \\PC0007\John

:Mark
    if %COMPUTERNAME%==PC0012 goto end
    net use y: \\PC0012\Mark


:end
```

If you can change the computername of every person to include their username, it is possible to simplify the script, but this does mean the computername is going to be very strict, and people can only have 1 main computer. Lets assume you change the computername to John-PC, or effectively `%USERNAME%-PC`, you could then create this simple logon script:

```
::  -- Login script: Maps Extra share if user is not on main computer

    if %COMPUTERNAME%==%USERNAME%-PC goto end
    net use y: \\%USERNAME%-PC\%USERNAME%

:end
```

Of course, this does mean, that on every computer, you have to share the folder that the user gets access to, and name the share their username.

Comment: Thank you for your input. That's pretty much what I have at the moment, a customized script for each user.

Comment: That's the only way to do it if you want to follow this train of thought.